# How can I sort widgets in GWT?

Tags: gwt, sorting

I have a list of widgets which needs to be sorted. I want to create a container for these list of widgets to re-sort them each time new widget is added. How can I do it?

I can see the following ways:

1. a straightforward way is place them into arraylist and sort via Comparator, but after a new element is added we have to remove all list from container and add them again, in a new order.
2. use some sorting container. i have found only CellTable for this. But actually I dont need its rich functionality - I have only one column, dont need to sort on user events, only when new element added or removed, - so is there something else I can utilize in my use case?

GWT 2.4

PS
Actually, I am looking for something, that can be expressed like "widget container backed by widget collection", i.e. I change collection - container changes its contents, how can I implement this, or where can I find it?

PPS
The widgets can be different, thats why I dont think I can use CellTable easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no straightforward way of re-sorting the elements in the DOM after you add a new widget.
When the widgets are attached you cannot just move them (change their position in the document structure) without detaching and re-attaching. 
Well, with absolute positioning you can just change the left-top coordinates to move the items, if it is what you need.

I had a similar problem to solve when I had to sort TreeItem elements (no built-in sort method available). As a workaround, I read all the children into the list and remove them from the parent widget at the same time, then sort these items using Comparator and add them back to parent from the sorted list. Everything is in a single sort() method, which encapsulates all required functionality and kind of simplifies understanding of this code.

> "widget container backed by widget collection"

I would like to learn about one like that that also can do sorting and re-attaching on the fly. But it still will be backed by the same detaching-attaching I assume. I would recommend you to write one yourself, that will fit your particular needs. Either you need a Tree or a FlowPanel or anything else - you can extend that and add sort() logic according to context. And override add() method accordingly. So, your first option looks like a possible solution to me.

Comment: Thanks, alexp. Finally I ended up with writing a method that finds a correct place of element before sorting, and inserts new widget exactly in that place. FlowPanel has insert(widget, index) method for this. Your method of sorting all widgets after insertion is also a good solution. By the way, here I asked what is more efficient in theory of algorythms: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219835/what-is-faster-sort-n-elements-or-insert-n-elements-one-by-one-in-correct-plac