# What is faster: sort n elements, or insert n elements one by one in correct place?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Generally, what is better: insert N elements in some collection and then sort it, or find out the correct place for the element before insert and insert it exactly in that place (repeat N times)?

Comment: What you describe in your second alternative is insertion sort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It is very dependent** on the data structure and application in use.

Note that inserting an element in an *array* requires shifting all the following elements to the right, which results in `O(n)` insertion.

A [Binary Search Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) however, allows insertion in `O(logn)`, but is less [cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) efficient then an array - and thus slower.

On the other hand, inserting and then sorting results in high **[latency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latency_%28engineering%29)** after the last element was inserted [The `O(nlogn)` sort].

Also - if you are going to query very often - but add elements seldom - you want to avoid sorting too often - and keeping elements in order is an easy way to achieve this.

Comment: This is the better answer, as it explains what the different scenarios are and how they impact sort time.  In the general case, the only correct answer is "it depends".

Answer (score 1):

Without making any assumption on the input, sorting takes nlog(n) time. Inserting an element takes O(n) time (linked list). So, sorting after all insertions is faster.

Answer (score 1):

This is better

> "insert N elements in some collection and then sort it"

because one can use `O(nlogn)` algorithm to sort. Where as this

> "find out the correct place for the element before insert and insert
>   it exactly in that place (repeat N times)?"

is insertion sort, known for worst case of `O(n^2)`.

That said, insertion sort is online algorithm. i.e. you don't need to know the whole data in advance to start sorting. Consider the data being generated by some other program running in parallel. Here insertion sort makes sense. Where as the other approach require whole data to be in place.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your data structure. Note though that to find out the right place before insertion you have to sort your elements somehow, which requires them to be already stored in a data structure. Can you provide additional information on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You can certainly sort your elements as you insert them.  It is called insertion sort. [Wikipedia Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)

Comment: Which is the same as just performing a sorting algorithm on the collection currently used to store the elements, except you can change the data structure used on the fly, which is why I asked for more details.

Comment: Look at amit's answer.  He very clearly shows the difference between sorting as you insert and sorting afterwards. It has the same end-effect, but it has a totally different impact on insertion/sort times.